# Stock Android OS downloading [AOSP] and sync issue

Tags: android, android-source

I have started my AOSP download with lot of hiccups.
I followed the google official site instructions.

```
$ mkdir ~/aosp/bin

$ PATH=~/aosp/bin:$PATH

$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/aosp/bin/repo

$ chmod a+x ~/aosp/bin/repo

$ mkdir zero

$ cd zero

$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"

$ git config --global user.email "you@example.com

$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4.2_r1

$ repo sync -j2 -f
```

As of now my *.repo* folder is 40GB and sync is still on its been 2 days. Please can anybody help me, all I need is KitKat OS.
Also could anyone enlighten me about project-object and project directories in repo directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: improved formatting & grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
 repo sync -j2 -f
```

You are synchronizing everything, which is huge. Give this a try:

```
 repo sync -j8 -c
```

This will only synch the initialized manifest, which is not as big. When you don't specify a manifest name with -m option, if falls to look for `default.xml`, which as I can see in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/refs/heads/android-4.4.2_r1 that's the manifest file for the branch you want.

Also `-j` specifies the threads used, nowadays you can give `-j8` at least a try.

With `-f` you force the download, this does not affect on the size of what you download, nor the speed. You can drop it if desired.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What do you think i should now ?
stop the on going sync initiated by repo sync -j2 -f and start again with repo sync -j8 -c ? or 
let it complete as i am at 42 GB
Will stopping the ongoing sync and doing repo sync -j8 -c remove the previously downloaded data ?

Comment: Yes, I would stop it, it's not going to erase the projects that are already synched.

If you think my answer suits you, consider approving it and/or upvoting it.

Comment: So just as a check i will stop the ongoing sync initiated by  repo sync -j2 -f and start again with repo sync -j8 -c.
do i have to run any other command before repo sync -j8 -c now ?

Comment: No you don't. The repo has been already initialized, that step is only necessary if you want to switch branches or manifest file declaration

Comment: i have stopped my sync initiated by repo sync -j2 -f. what do i do next ?
1. repo sync -j4 -c ? 
2. any other command ?
please help me through this @Olaia 
thanks in advance

Comment: repo sync -j8 -c
Nothing else. The repo has been already initialized, that step is only necessary if you want to switch branches or manifest file declaration

Comment: Thanks a ton @Olaia . will confirm on completion

Comment: can you guide me about which are the important folder i should be concerned about!
1. i have manifest, manifest.git, project-object, projects, repo in my .repo folder.
2. how to build this android OS for custom arm board ?

Comment: If you open the default.xml in directory manifests, you will see all the git projects that you should have in the root directory, and the exact path.

For building the OS for custom arm, I am afraid there is no instant and fast answer. I suggest you try to find information and go step by step and ask detailed questions when required.

Comment: where will my root directory be present ?
1. project-objects or 
2. projects ?

Thank you again.

Comment: and also can tell you tell me why are folders named with .git like abi.git, bionic.git in project and project-object folders !?

Comment: If you open the default.xml in directory manifests, you will see all the git projects that you should have in the root directory, Your root directory is where you did the repo init. All the directories that have .git, is because those are git projects themselves. The manifest (default.xml) is the list of all git projects that AOSP has.
For further questions please open new questions, this is a way too long comment history.

Comment: hey @Olaia i get it its really long for comments.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710339/instructions-for-aosp-download-of-4-4-2-version-os

can you please give me the detailed instruction to get what i want in this new post please ?

Answer (score 0):

After a week's struggle completed the repo sync of KITKAT OS from google. even though you select only a particular OS, It will go upto 58 GB. Out of that 58 GB your KITKAT OS will be only of 9.5 GB. Rest is your .repo in your WORKING DIRECTORY. After sync is complete you will find your OS source in your WORKING DIRECTORY along side .repo.

STEPS:

$ mkdir ~/bin

$ PATH=~/bin:$PATH

$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo

$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

$ mkdir WORKING_DIRECTORY

$ cd WORKING_DIRECTORY

$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"

$ git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b OS version

check with google's "source code tags and build" page to select your OS version.

$ repo sync -j18 -c

flags that can be used with repo sync

sync-j - The value for this will be the number of threads to use when syncing the system. Parallelization helps get the job done quicker, but could also get the computer or the network stuck. Using 4 threads is what commonly used for syncing.

sync-c - syncing only the current branch/tag from git. This will checkout for each project only the current branch/tag that we specify for it, and not any other branches that exists on the repository. This will help save some space and bandwidth (and also time), but if you’ll need to switch between branches on a specific project later on - you’ll need to fetch it manually.

it took 8 days for me to get this done as my internet speed is slow (100kbps).

Thank you @Olaia for all the help. hope this helps for anyone out there.