# How to download AOSP for 4.4.2 version OS?

Tags: android

Can anyone help me with the detailed instructions other than what google provides [https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html]
$repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4.2_r1
$repo sync -j18 -c 
is what i did. it is tagging everything.
help me tackle this guys.

- [new tag]         android-5.1.1_r14 -> android-5.1.1_r14

  - [new tag]         android-5.1.1_r13 -> android-5.1.1_r13
  - [new tag]         android-5.1.1_r12 -> android-5.1.1_r12
  - [new tag]         android-5.1.1_r10 -> android-5.1.1_r10
  - [new tag]         android-5.1.1_r1 -> android-5.1.1_r1
  - [new tag]         android-5.1.0_r5 -> android-5.1.0_r5
  - [new tag]         android-5.1.0_r4 -> android-5.1.0_r4
  - [new tag]         android-5.1.0_r3 -> android-5.1.0_r3
  - [new tag]         android-5.1.0_r1 -> android-5.1.0_r1
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.2_r3 -> android-5.0.2_r3
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.2_r1 -> android-5.0.2_r1
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.1_r1 -> android-5.0.1_r1
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.0_r7 -> android-5.0.0_r7
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.0_r6 -> android-5.0.0_r6
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.0_r5.1 -> android-5.0.0_r5.1
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.0_r5 -> android-5.0.0_r5
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.0_r4 -> android-5.0.0_r4
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.0_r3 -> android-5.0.0_r3
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.0_r2 -> android-5.0.0_r2
  - [new tag]         android-5.0.0_r1 -> android-5.0.0_r1
  - [new tag]         android-4.4w_r1 -> android-4.4w_r1
  - [new tag]         android-4.4_r1.2.0.1 -> android-4.4_r1.2.0.1
  - [new tag]         android-4.4_r1.2 -> android-4.4_r1.2
  - [new tag]         android-4.4_r1.1.0.1 -> android-4.4_r1.1.0.1
  - [new tag]         android-4.4_r1.1 -> android-4.4_r1.1
  - [new tag]         android-4.4_r1.0.1 -> android-4.4_r1.0.1
  - [new tag]         android-4.4_r1 -> android-4.4_r1
  - [new tag]         android-4.4_r0.9 -> android-4.4_r0.9
  - [new tag]         android-4.4_r0.8 -> android-4.4_r0.8
  - [new tag]         android-4.4_r0.7 -> android-4.4_r0.7
  - [new tag]         android-4.4.4_r2.0.1 -> android-4.4.4_r2.0.1
  - [new tag]         android-4.4.4_r2 -> android-4.4.4_r2
  - [new tag]         android-4.4.4_r1.0.1 -> android-4.4.4_r1.0.1
  - [new tag]         android-4.4.4_r1 -> android-4.4.4_r1

Dont leave me hanging here guys please do help !
thank in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stock Android OS downloading \[AOSP\] and sync issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642929/stock-android-os-downloading-aosp-and-sync-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But there is no faster way, as answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642929/stock-android-os-downloading-aosp-and-sync-issue).
You are gonna have to be patient.

```
$ repo sync -j8 -c
```

**EDITED**

Also, depending on your needs, you may want to try to pass `--depth=1`, to your repo init in order to get a shallow clone of the repositories. I have never tried it myself but theoretically, it should take less time/space, although you will be missing the whole history.

Comment: .repo is at 56GB and still going on....

what steps should i follow if i had to start all over again,  like from initializing repo for 4.4.2_r1.

Comment: If it has common commits, those will not be downloaded again. But yes, it takes a lot of space.

Comment: and the steps for fresh android 4.4.2_r1 download starting from installing repo ?

Comment: You would need to initialize the repo pointing to the branch you want.
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b <<the branch you want>>
And then, sync it again.
$ repo sync -j18 -c

Comment: Thanks @Olaia that should work.

can u explain me when to use this command 
repo init -b master -m base-for-3.0-gpl.xml 

i found this here https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html#source-code-tags-and-builds

thanks in advance

Comment: That's when the manifest doesn't have the default name (default.xml), you need to specify it. 
Again, already explained in your other question. Looks like you are going in circles

Comment: t
$ mkdir ~/aosp
$ cd aosp
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ PATH=~/aosp/bin:$PATH
$ curl storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo >~/aosp/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/aosp/bin/repo
$ mkdir zero
$ cd zero
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email "you@example.com
$ repo init -u android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4.2_r1
$ repo sync -j2 -c
So these steps should get me kitkat AOSP and nothing else right ? @Olaia

Comment: $ repo init -u android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b 4.4.2_r1 And then, $ repo sync -j18 -c 

i followed these steps and it is tagging not just kitkat even android 5,6,7

Answer (score 0):

after a week's struggle completed the repo sync of KITKAT OS from google.
even though you select only a particular OS, It will go upto 58 GB. Out of that 58 GB your KITKAT OS will be only of 9 GB. Rest is your .repo in your WORKING DIRECTORY. After sync is complete you will find your OS source in your WORKING DIRECTORY along side .repo.

STEPS:

$ mkdir ~/bin

$ PATH=~/bin:$PATH

$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo

$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

$ mkdir WORKING_DIRECTORY

$ cd WORKING_DIRECTORY

$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"

$ git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b OS version

check with google's "source code tags and build" page to select your OS version.

$ repo sync -j18 -c

flags that can be used with repo sync

sync-j - The value for this will be the number of threads to use when syncing the system. Parallelization helps get the job done quicker, but could also get the computer or the network stuck. Using 4 threads is what commonly used for syncing.

sync-c - syncing only the current branch/tag from git. This will checkout for each project only the current branch/tag that we specify for it, and not any other branches that exists on the repository. This will help save some space and bandwidth (and also time), but if you’ll need to switch between branches on a specific project later on - you’ll need to fetch it manually.

it took 8 days for me to get this done as my internet speed is slow (100kbps).

Thank you @Olaia for all the help.
hope this helps for anyone out there.